# Create arrays via code

Tags: ruby

I was wondering if it is possible to create dynamic arrays, i.e., arrays with code depending on the user input. If the user enters `3`, code creates three arrays. Or if user enters `5`, code creates five arrays. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Do you want these arrays to be created in a double array or separately?

Comment: Separately so i'm able to reference them individually later on.

Comment: You can reference a single array within a double array with double_array[0], double_array[1] etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
print 'How many arrays? ' #=> suppose 5 is entered
arrays = Array.new(gets.to_i) { [] } #=> [[], [], [], [], [], []]
```

This will create an array holding 5 different arrays. If you want each to be stored in a separate variable, you can use the fact that Ruby allows you to dynamically create instance variables:

```
print 'How many arrays? '
number = gets.to_i
number.times.each do |i| # if number is 5, i will be 0,1,2,3,4
  instance_variable_set(:"@array_#{i}", Array.new)
end

p @array_0, @array_1, @array_2, @array_3, @array_4
```

Suppose we entered 3 here, the first 3 instance variables (`array_0` through `array_3`) will print `[]`, while the last 2 will print `nil` (since they lack a value).

Answer (score 1):

```
def create_arrays(n)
  array_collection = []
  n.times {array_collection.push([])}
  array_collection
end
```